# Server side routing for Polymer Application

Tags: routes, polymer-2.x

If I use "polymer serve" to start web application, refreshing any page shows the same page I am on.

Using my own go lang server gives me 404 error on page refresh.

I have to reroute every page request to index.html which shows the first application page. But I don't want to show the first page.

How to route on server side to get same behavior as "polymer serve"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default `app-location` routes using the pathname portion of the URL.
>   This has broad browser support but it does require cooperation of the
>   backend server.

The cooperation of the backend server is something like [RequestDispatcher.forward()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)) in Java. You should find how to do it with Go lang.

> An app-location can be configured to use the hash part of a URL
>   instead using the use-hash-as-path attribute, like so:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
```

Ref. https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route#hashes-vs-paths

Comment: Thanks. Following worked:<app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>.  And then changed link as : <a name="view1" href="#/view1">View One</a>